# High density Silverlight charting control

Tags: silverlight, charts

I've been looking into Silverlight charting controls to display a large number of samples, (~10,000 data points in five separate series - ~50k points all up).

I have found the existing options produced by Dundas, Visifire, Microsoft etc to be extremely poor performers when displaying more than a few hundred data points.

I believe the performance issues with existing chart controls is caused by the heavy use of vector graphics.
Ergo one solution would be a client-side chart control that uses the WritableBitmap class to generate a raster chart.

Before I fall too far down the wheel re-invention rabbit hole - **has anyone found a third party or OSS control that will manage large numbers of data points on a sparkline**?

Comment: Hello there, take a look at SciChart, which is able to render multiple series totalling 100,000 datapoints at 30FPS on the performance demo (3,000,000 datapoints per second). This is a new offering and will be ready to go live early in Q1 2012.

It doesn't have all the features that LOB charts have, however does support multiple chart types, a basic cursor, zooming, panning and axis scaling and very high performance. 

http://www.abtsoftware.co.uk/News/tabid/93/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/16/SciChart_Technology_Preview_-_Fast_WPFSilverlight_Stock_Chart_Performance_Demo.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Check out Visiblox ( http://www.visiblox.com/ ) Charts. I'm working on a telemetry application at the minute which uses three of their charts in the same Silverlight component, plotting about 36,000 points in total, and there is very little slowdown in terms of performance, if any at all.

They have a high performance example on their website here - http://www.visiblox.com/examples/LargeDataSets. I chose to use Visiblox after loooking at the following blog post:

New performance comparison: http://www.visifire.com/blog/2011/12/02/fast-silverlight-charts/

Old performance comparison: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/12/visiblox-visifire-dynamicdatadisplay-charting-performance-comparison/

My telemetry example is now part of a [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverTrack.aspx) article that I have created, if you want to take a look!

Answer (score 3):

Based on the recommendations here, I have just trialled Visiblox and Infragistics.

**Visiblox** has a good developer experience, clean APIs, no bloat. While the performance is OK for a few thousand datapoints, performance breaks down as you go into the 100k range. Here's [the Visiblox sample](http://www.visiblox.com/examples/LargeDataSets) with a few thousand points (you can download the sample and just tweak the number of datapoints).

Now, the common argument here is that you should not bind that much data to a chart anyway, but should do some trimming beforehand. I do agree with that, but ideally, I want a chart control that does take care of that for me. Getting Zooming, Panning and all that right are non-trivial tasks and I'd be happy to shell out a few 100$ to get that functionality. It's plain economic common sense to not reinvent the wheel here.

**Infragistics** certainly gets that right. I can bind a million odatapoints and get smooth peformance. Here's [the Infragistics sample](http://samples.infragistics.com/sldv/RunSamples.aspx?cn=data-chart#/data-chart/binding-high-volume-data).

However, Infragistics installs a lot of junk (a local IIS web app with the samples you can also see online) and besides the (excellent) samples and the code-level documentation, I do miss some high-level introduction to each component and it's individual modules.

Since a lot of people on SO recommend **Telerik** controls for their clean APIs, Documentation and Developer Support, I did also take a look at their chart control. However, I must admit I find it rather slow (Zooming takes roughly 500-1000ms, which is too long to feel smooth). 
Here's [the Telerik sample](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Sampling).

Comment: I am currently looking into [mindscapehq][http://www.mindscapehq.com/demo/silverlightelements/demopage.html#/ChartOverviewPage] chart. Compared to Infragistics, it does achieve good performance even when plotting non-equidistant x values (a true x,y graph).

Answer (score 2):

Visifire is the fastest chart now. Check out the blog link below. 
http://www.visifire.com/blog/2011/12/02/fast-silverlight-charts/

The Chart image says Visifire is 3 to 4x faster than Visiblox..!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Before you start playing around with WritableBitmap on your own take a look at `WriteableBitmapEx` from René Schulte, he blogs about it [here](http://kodierer.blogspot.com/2009/12/writeablebitmapex-writeablebitmap.html).  Awesome stuff.

Comment: Excellent suggestion! I've since had a fiddle with WritableBitmapEx to write a small game, but haven't gotten started on anything charts wise quite yet.
Quite a nice library. Thanks Anthony.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any OSS or 3rd party controls that'll do what you need.

The one case where I've had the need for 100K+ of datapoints, we made it work by keeping it simple. The biggest perf killer was the number of elements within each datapoint. By keeping the element a simple ellipse with a static brush fill the app was rather snappy.

Comment: Hello there, which component did you use in the end that was able to render 100k points?

Answer (score 1):

Infragistics claims to be able to handle massive amounts of data in their recently released xamDataChart.

http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/silverlight/data-visualization/xam-web-data-chart.aspx#Overview

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Telerik sample you are looking for can be found [here](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/ZoomScroll). It shows large amounts of data that you can actually zoom in/out of. They also have a Server Load ["Performance" Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/LiveData) as well. Here is an example of the [Scatter Chart](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery/Scatter) with hundreds of data points.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the Telerik charting controls? <strike>Here is a link to one of their demos where they are using 100.000 data points:

http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Sampling</strike>

I should also mention that I have not used the charting controls myself, so I cannot vouch for them. But the demos look good to me.

**EDIT**:
The link above has gone stale. Here is a link to the latest incarnation of the Telerik charting control They call it ChartView now:
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#ChartView/FirstLook

Comment: Yeah, the Telerik components have been updated since then. I have updated the link.